# Android Button layout with big text size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I'm trying to make two identical buttons with the same height, but when the text is too long (the second button) then breaks markup. How can I fix it?

xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <Button

            android:text="test"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="Arterial tension disturbance"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are the buttons aligned vertically or horizontally?

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "breaks markup"?

Comment: Buttons heights are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add android:singleLine="true"

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:singleLine="true"

        android:text="test"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="Arterial tension disturbance"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use wrap_content instead of 0dp

```
    <Button
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="Arterial tension disturbance"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Comment: then you'll break the weight rule... and the buttons will no more have the same width

Comment: it's not right, because if I take wrap_content it will make my button bigger than first and they will not be the same

Comment: or you can use fill_parent so that buttons will fill your layout width

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: (Edited)

```
<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:weightSum="100" >


       <Button
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:text="yourText"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="50" />

      <Button
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:text="yourText"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="50" />
```

Comment: It's completely wrong!! In Buttons you should have **layout_weight="50"**, not weightSum. And you can use lower values. And you must set the button widths to **0dp**.

Comment: weightSum didn't help!

Comment: extremely sorry. My Bad! that should be "layout_weight=50" within <Button > tag

Comment: well! you should set your view width to fill parent if you are using weightSum. Because, it will only have half of the space left for it. So, when you are using it fill parent it will take only that half part. Just give it a try. It will work definitely (Insha-Allah). :)